# How can I enable syntax highlighting in vim?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, development

I have the usual `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax on` commands in my `.vimrc` and can verify that filetype is correctly recognised. But no syntax highlighting. What can I do? This worked out of the box in Ubuntu.

Comment: see [here](http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-syntax-highlighting), if useful :)

Comment: @Ravan Well, as I wrote, I have these commands in m `.vimrc` so it's got tob something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had some stuff in my `.vimrc` which did not belong there (copied it from OSX where I use iTerm).

Specifically, this was the problem

```
" Solarized colorscheme
if !has('gui_running')
   let g:solarized_termcolors=256
endif
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
hi Visual ctermbg=105
hi MatchParen cterm=bold ctermbg=125 ctermfg=0
hi Normal ctermfg=253
```

I did not investigate which part exactly, but I did not even have the solarized colorscheme installed, so that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting does not appear to be enabled in the default build of VIM included with Elementary OS Freya, see below

`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:02)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             -farsi           -mouse_sgr       -tag_old_static
<snipped>
-ex_extra        -mouse_jsbterm   -syntax`